# how many workshops do we need to get maximum adjacency bonuses?

Tags: xcom-enemy-within

I uses a 3 by 3 workshop with 12 connections.

If I remove 3, I got 9 connections. So 8 seems to be the final number right assuming 10% adjacency bonuses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum adjacency bonus depends on your version, since the bonus is greater in Enemy Within.

In Enemy Unknown, the bonus is 7% so you need 15 for over 100%. To get 15 adjacencies, you'll need 11 workshops (or 10 plus the Foundry which also counts) in a 3x4 layout with a corner missing. This may not be practical, since you also need space for uplinks, power, labs, and the plot critical buildings.

If you are playing Enemy Within, the bonus is 10% so you will only need 10 adjacencies. This needs 8 workshops (or 6 workshops, the Foundry and Cybernetics Lab). There are two possible layouts for this- 2x4 or 3x3 with a corner missing.